# Stuck at dotnet publish step on Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are having a problem with the pipelines in our project.
We are using the .Net Core 3.1 version.

For the last 2 months, we have been having a problem in the "dotnet build" step in the pipeline. Builds without this step are finished in a few minutes, while other builds take 1-2 hours.
[image: Pipelines]

There is no error when it comes to the dotnet publish step.
E.g :
[image: dotnet publish step]

PS: pipelines are running on linux server.

Comment: That's cryptic. Try adding --verbosity diagnostic to the dotnet publish command in the pipeline. Maybe also try it running it on your local machine.

Comment: This is just warnings and it is ok. If you use dontet 3.1 you should have usedotnet task. Please share you pipeline definition as without details it would be difficult to help.

Comment: Please set the variable `system.debug` to true and share the log here.